# file_put_contents() is very slow when working with lots of images

Tags: php, image, file

I must save ~5,000 images to disk and my script is running very slow. Among others, my script contains a `foreach` loop which saves images to disk. I guess the problem is with `file_put_contents` function, because when I comment it, everything works super fine.

Here is my code:

```
file_put_contents($pathimg . '.jpg', file_get_contents($url));
file_put_contents($pathimg . '.jpg', file_get_contents($url3));
```

Is there a way to save these images faster?

Comment: Perhaps your disk is running slow

Comment: its based on your system process speed i tihnk..

Comment: May be your system is performing too much I/O. Allow more memory to your php process might help modify the memory_limit in you php.ini to  `memory_limit = 512MB`. Also try a implement a sleep that would prevent your script to write 5000 images all at once

Comment: Thinking about io speeds here - How large are the images? i.e. what is the total size of data that you expect to write to to the disk? Are the source images and destination images on the same disk? Have the disks been 'defragged' recently? I notice that you are using 'url'  to read the images -  How quickly can you read the images files (megabytes per second)?

Comment: @RyanVincent images have ~20kb, the total size I supposed it can be up to 1 GB. The source images and destionation are not on the same disk. Disks have not been defragged. I don't know the answer to the last question..

Comment: Assuming that you have all the files locally and a 'disk write' speed of about 10 MB/Sec (conservative) then it should take - about 2 minutes to write all the files to disk. How long is it actually taking? Hmm -- i mean is it taking a lot longer than 2 minutes?

Comment: Yes...it does. I ran the script 4 minutes ago..and still running...But I made an experiment and I realised that reading the image is actually the problem, not writing it. And reading images with file_get_contents or using curl doesn't make big difference

Comment: I would really like to do that. But the images are on a distinct server.I don't even have access at that server. I am using an api to take over some information along with these images.

Comment: My understanding is that,  the file transfer speed is limited by the source, which is external. Thank you for clarifying that. There is not a lot you can do about that except maybe to negotiate a higher download bandwidth with them.

Answer (score 1):

The code you posted is doing file_get_contents and file_put_contents in the same line. The slow speed that you're seeing can be either the image download (file_get_contents) or the disk write (file_put_contents) - However, the speed of write would mostly likely be negligible to that of writing the image to disk.

You probably should benchmark both of them separately to find out what's causing the slow behaviour.

Comment: Hei thank you. I figure out that file_get_contents was running too slow. I replaced it with CURL and still doesn't run as I expected...

Answer (score 0):

You can use CURL which is more faster. Here is the function you can use.

```
function grab_image($url,$saveto){
    $ch = curl_init ($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER,1);
    $raw=curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close ($ch);
    if(file_exists($saveto)){
        unlink($saveto);
    }
    $fp = fopen($saveto,'x');
    fwrite($fp, $raw);
    fclose($fp);
}
```

Ensure that in php.ini allow_url_fopen is enable.