# Canvas to dataUrl large image file (1750 × 1250)

Tags: javascript, php, canvas, base64

I am creating image editor using JavaScript and ended up with medium image file with resolution 1750 × 1250. I decoded the image from canvas using `base64` and then I sent it to server side using PHP.

Here's the deal, when I am trying to save that image using `file_put_contents` it taking a **long** time, nearly 5 minutes to save the image. Any ideas how can I trim the time processing? It just doesn't make sense editing that image with medium resolution with that time.

I have try with another method such as: `curl_init`, `fopen()`, and etc.

I have searching for

[file_put_contents() is very slow when working with lots of images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28743918/file-put-contents-is-very-slow-when-working-with-lots-of-images)

but i didn't find answers.

Comment: please refer this link and you can use CURL instead. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28743918/file-put-contents-is-very-slow-when-working-with-lots-of-images)

Comment: **please read:** [What should you do when someone answers your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Yosafat Ksatria, if you are satisfied with my answer, please mark it as accepted on the left side from answer. In other case please write a feedback.

Answer (score 0):

The slow speed could be the upload (not a download) time to the server.

I have read in your profile, that you are the student from ITHB (in Indonesia?). In your country people have not fast internet speed and upload speed is most very slowly.

You could find the upload time if you check it after upload the image (in `base64` format) to the server at once before you use `file_put_contents`.

And you can reduce the upload time if you will send your image not in `base64` format to the server. You can do it for example like this:

```
function base64ToBlob(base64Image)
{
    var binary = atob(base64Image.split(',')[1]),
        img_buffer = [];
        i = 0;

    for(; i < binary.length; i++)
        img_buffer.push(binary.charCodeAt(i));

    return new Blob([new Uint8Array(img_buffer)], {type: 'image/jpg'})
}

var base64Image = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg'),
    formData = new FormData(),
    xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

formData.append('image', base64ToBlob(base64Image));

xhr.open('POST', 'imageSave.php', true);
xhr.send(formData);
```